# How can I sort strings as numbers in an array

Tags: string, powershell, sorting, numbers

```
$csv = Import-Csv $InputFileName
$AllValues = $csv.FamNumber
$Ht= $AllValues | Group-Object | Sort-Object Name | Where{$_.name -ne "DUMMY"}

The output is:
Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                                                
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                                
2     1                         {1, 1}                                                                                                                                               
2     10                        {10, 10}                                                                                                                                             
1     11                        {11}                                                                                                                                                 
1     12                        {12}                                                                                                                                                 
2     13                        {13, 13}                                                                                                                                             
1     14                        {14}                                                                                                                                                 
1     15                        {15}                                                                                                                                                 
1     16                        {16}                                                                                                                                                 
2     17                        {17, 17}                                                                                                                                             
2     18                        {18, 18}                                                                                                                                             
3     19                        {19, 19, 19}                                                                                                                                         
1     2                         {2}                                                                                                                                                  
1     20                        {20}
```

What I want is that the 'Name' column is sorted like:
1
2
10
11
12
13
14
etc.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: `Sort-Object` accepts script blocks in addition to plain property names, so try `Sort-Object { [int] $_.Name }` (and that will fail for `DUMMY` records, so you probably want to do that `Where` first -- before the `Group-Object` would be optimal, in fact).

Comment: Just to spell out why `Sort-Object Name` didn't work: the grouped objects are invariably _strings_, due to having been imported from a CSV, and the resulting _lexical_ sorting is not the same as _numerical_ sorting. Compare `'1', '10', '9' | Sort-Object` to `1, 10, 9 | Sort-Object`